# Why can't I view some user profiles from their posts?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, users

I have searched for answers to some questions where I got a good (often the best) solution from Stack Overflow. However, I was unable to see the author's profile pages.

The link was disabled, why does that happen? Is it only for me alone, because I have a temporarily suspended account? Are there any other reason for those cases? I've attached an image to show what I'm describing:

[image]

Why can't I go to the author's profile anymore?

Comment: Those users are either deleted/removed or they didn't had valid registered account at the time the post was was posted..

Comment: Because those user accounts do not exist.  Why those cease to exit might be for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @CRUSADER Thanks. post your answer i will accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were unable to see the profile pages because those users were either deleted/removed or they didn't had valid registered account at the time the post was was posted.

Answer (score 0):

Either the user account is removed (deleted) or the question is migrated from other stack exchange sites.